# tensorflow gpu utilization 0 - tensorflow model only use GPU when validating.. not when training

Tags: keras, deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I'm currently training a tensorflow model with GPU.

I tested the code below and GPU until rose up to 60%, which means my GPU settings are just fine.

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0



model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

Training my custom model, I found that GPU is not utilized at all  (0% when nvidia-smi) only when it is training.

After training, calculating validation accuracy(in the same epoch with training), GPU until gets high enough.

At the second epoch, training gets started, GPU until goes down to 0 again.

What is going on here?

```
####################### MODEL #######################
class FM_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, field_dims, embedding_size):
        super(FM_layer, self).__init__()
        self.w0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[1],
                                               mean=0.0, 
                                               stddev=0.1),
                                               name='w0')
        
        self.wixi_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = sum(field_dims),
                                                         output_dim=1,
                                                         name='wixi',
                                                         embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
                                                         
                                                         )
   
    def call(self, inputs, latent_inputs):

        # linear_terms
        sum_wixi = tf.math.reduce_sum(self.wixi_embeddings(inputs=inputs), axis=1)
        linear_terms = tf.math.add(sum_wixi, self.w0)

        # interarction _terms
        square_of_sum = tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(latent_inputs, [1], keepdims=True) )
        sum_of_square = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(latent_inputs), [1], keepdims=True)
        interaction_terms = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(square_of_sum - sum_of_square, [2])
        
        linear_terms = tf.reshape(linear_terms, [-1, 1])
        interaction_terms = tf.reshape(interaction_terms, [-1, 1])
        y_fm = tf.math.add(linear_terms , interaction_terms) # batch_size, 1
      
        return y_fm




class Deep_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, field_dims, embedding_size):
        super(Deep_layer, self).__init__()
        
        self.field_dims = field_dims
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size  
        
        self.layers1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)
        self.layers2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)
        self.layers3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
        self.dropout3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)
        self.layers4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())
        self.dropout4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)
        
        self.batch1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.batch2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.batch3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.batch4 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        
        self.final = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='tanh')#tf.nn.leaky_relu ) # relu
        
    
    def call(self, latent_inputs):
        latent_inputs = tf.reshape(latent_inputs, [-1, len(self.field_dims)*self.embedding_size]) #flatten
        y_deep = self.layers1(latent_inputs)
        y_deep = self.batch1(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.dropout1(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.layers2(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.batch2(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.dropout2(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.layers3(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.batch3(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.dropout3(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.layers4(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.batch4(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.dropout4(y_deep)
        y_deep = self.final(y_deep)

        return y_deep



class DeepFM(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, field_dims, offset, embedding_size):
        super(DeepFM, self).__init__()
        
        self.field_dims = field_dims
        self.offset = offset
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size    
        self.V_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim= sum(field_dims),
                                                   output_dim=embedding_size,
                                                   name='V',
                                                   embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
                                                     )
    
        self.fm_layer = FM_layer(field_dims, embedding_size)
        self.deep_layer = Deep_layer(field_dims, embedding_size)

    
    def call(self, inputs):

        inputs = tf.math.add(inputs, self.offset)
        latent_inputs = self.V_embeddings(inputs=inputs)
        
        # 1) fm Component
        y_fm = self.fm_layer(inputs, latent_inputs)
        # 2) Deep Component
        y_deep = self.deep_layer(latent_inputs)
        # Concatenation
        y_fm = tf.reshape(y_fm, [-1, 1])
        y_deep = tf.reshape(y_deep, [-1, 1])
        y_pred = tf.math.sigmoid(tf.math.add(y_fm, y_deep))
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1, 1])

        return y_pred




deepfm_model = DeepFM(
                    field_dims=FIELD_DIMS,
                    offset = OFFSET,
                    embedding_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE
                    )

deepfm_model.compile(
                loss=BinaryCrossentropy(),
                optimizer = 'Adam',
                metrics=['binary_accuracy', 'AUC']
                )

history = deepfm_model.fit(
           X_train, 
           Y_train,
           epochs= 30,
           validation_data=(X_val[:], Y_val[:]),
           batch_size = 1024
           )
```

Is my custom model not able to use GPU fundamentally?

Comment: Maybe you could try decorating all of the `call` functions in your custom model with [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function)?
Intuitively I would have thought that this is not necessary when also using `model.fit`, but it might be worth a try

Comment: EDIT: Actually it should be enough to decorate the `call` function of DeepFM

Comment: I already tried that.. but didn't work..  Thanks for advise

Comment: Then could it be a problem of your coding environment? What does the console output when you first import tensorflow, do you find anything reading CUDA error?